# Terminate indefinitely running sub-command - inotify

Tags: bash, inotify

Imagine a scenario like so, where inotify calls another script which goes on forever

```sh
while inotifywait -e close_write ./<sample-file>; do 
    ./file.sh
done
```

Content `file.sh`:

```sh
while true; do
    sleep 5;
    echo "sample message";
done
```

Is there a way I can terminate the execution of the `file.sh` whenever `sample-file` gets updated?

Thanks!

Comment: You can test easier when you modify `file.sh` with `echo "$0: message: $*"` and call `./file.sh $(date)` or another changing argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run `file.sh` in the background, and keep track of it's running already or not. If it is, kill it before running it again. Example:

```
#!/bin/sh
bgpid=
trap 'kill $bgpid' 0 2 3 15 # Kill the background process when the parent exits
while inotifywait -e open ./input.txt; do
    if [ -n "$bgpid" ]; then
        echo "Killing existing file.sh on pid $bgpid"
        kill $bgpid
        bgpid=
    fi
    ./file.sh &
    bgpid=$!
done
```